# How do Solana Rust smart contracts handle arrays and vectors?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, solana

I know Solana does not have a HashMap data structure as a design pattern.

Does that mean developers should use program derived addresses (PDAs) for each user or stake pool instead of making an array/vector of users or stake pools for data storage?

Comment: In Solana, the programs cannot store state. Only accounts can store state. If you wish to store some kind of state for your program, it's best to use a PDA which is an account that only the program will have control over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is a bit subjective, since it's asking an opinion of how to handle storing lots of information on-chain with Solana.  Both options are possible: you can store a vector / array on-chain in one account, or you can use program-derived addresses as a sort of on-chain HashMap.  It's a tradeoff.

If you store a vector in an account, you are limited to the size allocated at the start, but it may be quicker and cheaper to store a certain number of values.

If you need to store a huge amount of data and you have a good model for generating keys, then creating accounts at program-derived addresses may be a good fit.  You will need to pay rent for each account, so it may be expensive if you're not storing a lot of data in each account.  You can use `solana rent <ACCOUNT_SIZE>` to estimate the costs for both approaches.

Comment: are there any github link that showcase project that is handling huge amount of data by generating accounts?

Comment: The best base example might be the associated-token-account program + token program.  Instead of one huge account for all of a user's tokens, the associated token account program creates a separate token account for each mint: https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account

Answer (score -2):

You can read the code here on their official example.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-lending/program/src/state/obligation.rs#L331
How they pack and unpack the vector is line 331.

Comment: I didn't vote this down, but FYI line 331 no longer works (because the link is to master). 

Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow sites for this reason. Can you put the code you're discussing into the answer?